# UISegmentedControl in TableViewCell not working. How to create outlet? Is it possible to have a segment control in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9

So the set up is that I have a view controller called settings. Within that vc, I have a container. I then have a Table View Controller that segues into the container via an "embed segue". (This is set up as a static table). When I run the app, the settings view controller displays with the table set inside the container view. How can I use that segment control in the settings view controller (parent class for settings vc is settings.swift)? The table view has the default UITableViewController as a parent class.

The left most screen is how it appears on my phone when I run it. (Right screen shot is different as I took that before simplifying it to just a segment control)

My question is how can I get the selectedsegmentindex from a segmented control (within a table view cell that belongs to a static table view)? Is it even possible? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is give the segmented control a nil  targeted action. That will successfully call the action handler implemented in any view controller up the hierarchy.